# Sql query to create following tables

Tags: sql

use the below table 1 to generate table 2

Table 1

```
Col1    A   B   C
------------------
N1      1   0   0 
N2      0   1   0
N3      1   0   0
```

Table 2
output

```
new_col
-------
N1 A
N2 B
N3 A
```

Also how to use Table 2 to generate table 1 above

Comment: Can you tell us what your DBMS is?

Comment: What if there are two "1" in a row?  Or none?

Answer (score 1):

Following SQL query can be help to get requested output:

```
SELECT Col1,IF(A=1,'A',IF(B=1,'B','C')) AS result FROM `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditinal with `CONCAT()` Function :

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1,' ',
                   CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END)
  FROM table1
```

provided you're on a DBMS with brand name such as MySQL, PostGRES, SQL Server. As an example, Oracle DB won't allow using more than two arguments for `CONCAT()` Function.

In order to create `table2`, use for most of the DBMS :

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT CONCAT(col1,' ',
                   CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END) AS new_col
  FROM table1
```

except for SQL Server in which prefer using :

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1,' ',
                   CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END,
                   CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END) AS new_col
  INTO table2                   
  FROM table1
```

In order to implement a reverse engineering(go back to original table), you need to consider the dialectics for each seperate database to handle string values. Assume you're using MySQL DB, then consider using :

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT SUBSTRING(new_col,1,instr(new_col,' ')-1) AS col1,
       CASE WHEN instr(new_col,'A') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS A,
       CASE WHEN instr(new_col,'B') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS B,
       CASE WHEN instr(new_col,'C') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C
  FROM table2
```

where I used a different table name (`table3`), since `table1` already exists.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e69269e373c18a2c66594f6f50a517b5)</kbd>

Btw, if Oracle DB is the case, then use :

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(col1,' '),
                     CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END||
                     CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END||
                     CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END) AS new_col
  FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one case statement. This works in Oracle.

```
SELECT col1
    || CASE 
        WHEN A = 1
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN B = 1
            THEN 'B'
        WHEN C = 1
            THEN 'C'
        END
NEW_COL
FROM table1
```

Comment: What if first row of table1 is `N1      1   0   1` ..?

Comment: It will result in A.

Comment: so, works for the current case but not generic. e.g. not work for every cases I mean. It should return AC indeed. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c4f17fba09efff7929be46eb5a43bb0)

Comment: There was no example for this case. It is safe to assume from the sample data that there is one “1” per record. Of course if this is not the case then you are right. But should it be AC or A,C or A or any other value.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want when there are multiple "1"s in a row.  This is a simple solution:

```
select id, A from t where A = 1
union all
select id, B from t where B = 1
union all
select id, C from t where C = 1;
```

In databases that support lateral joins, I would recommend:

```
select t.id, v.which
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('A', t.A), ('B', B), ('C', C)
     ) v(which, val)
where val = 1;
```